# Can not see the text in terminal

Tags: command-line

I am new at ubuntu. I installed pulse audio for ubuntu and suddenly the terminal stop responding with no text. I have tried removing and installing it again via the software center.

Uxterm works I tried typing:

```
sudo apt-get install terminal
```

but that did only says:

```
0 remove and 0 installed
```

and then I'm lost, and do not know what to do, and how to make it work, and can someone please help.

Answer (score 2):

Try using:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-terminal
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using only:

> sudo apt-get install gnome-terminal

Because you already removed it and reinstall won't help :D